# Unmarshaller failure

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

I have to mrss feeds form which I'm getting the content via unmarshalling process. They look like to have the same structure, but in one case it is always returning null as 'mediaContent'. Can someone help what is the difference between the two feeds?

returns null:
http://smrss.neulion.com/u/nhl/mrss/sights-and-sounds/vod.xml
working correctly:
http://smrss.neulion.com/u/nhl/mrss/news/news_mrss.xml

Comment: At first glance seems that namespaces are different .. first one is `http://search.yahoo.com/mrss`, and the second is `http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/`. The second has a `/` at the end.

Comment: Damn, I was looking into it to find the difference for hours but you are right, thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome, I added an answer in order to close this topic, accepts the answer :)

Comment: Did you solve this question? You should accept below answer in order to close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance seems that namespaces are different .. first one is `http://search.yahoo.com/mrss`, and the second is `http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/`. The second has a `/` at the end.